# Magento 2.2.1: Upgrade from 2.1.6

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2, magento-2.2.1, magento-upgrade

I am receiving the following error when clicking on a product link or accessing the product page. This was done after upgrading from Magento 2.1.6 to 2.2.1.

Also received other errors but resolved them.

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'attribute', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed. Line: 1010

Element 'attribute', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed. Line: 1010

Element 'attribute', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed. Line: 1011

Element 'attribute', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed. Line: 1011

Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'as': The attribute 'as' is not allowed. Line: 1048

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'attribute', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed. Line: 1010

Element 'attribute', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed. Line: 1010

Element 'attribute', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed. Line: 1011

Element 'attribute', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed. Line: 1011

Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'as': The attribute 'as' is not allowed. Line: 1048

0 .../vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('

1 .../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('

2 .../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewo...', Array)

3 .../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...', Array)

4 .../vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewo...', Array)

5 .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(125): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)

6 .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('

7 .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '\n

8 .../generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)

9 .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()

10 .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()

11 .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()

12 .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()

13 .../generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')

14 .../vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')

15 .../vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Noroute/Index.php(44): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor), 'no-route')

16 .../generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index->execute()

17 .../vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->execute()

18 .../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

19 .../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)

20 .../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

21 .../generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)

22 .../vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

23 .../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

24 .../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)

25 .../vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

26 .../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

27 .../vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

28 .../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

29 .../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

30 .../generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)

31 .../vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 32 .../vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() 33 .../index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) 34 {main}/
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you use some attributes in the product detail page layout that are not valid, like the ifconfig and remove. Search for them in your theme layout and try to remove them or replace them in another way.